# Dart Js-interop: how to declare function with callback?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm using node.js API from compiled Dart app. With package:js bindings for this api's:

```
    @JS('http')
    library http;
    import "package:js/js.dart";

    external Server createServer(
[ void requestListener(IncomingMessage request, ServerResponse response)])
```

And calling this from main.dart:

```
import "package:js/js.dart";
import "node_partly.dart" as http;

main() async {
  http.Server server = http.createServer(allowInterop(handler));
  server.listen(9876);
}

void handler(http.IncomingMessage request, http.ServerResponse response){
  response.write("Hello, from dart server! \n");
  response.write("You asked for ${request.url}");
  print(request.url);
  response.end();
}
```

Everything works fine.

But. Analyzer fails with error

> WARNING: The argument type 'JSFunction' cannot be assigned to the
>   parameter type '(IncomingMessage, ServerResponse) → void'. (
>   example/main.dart:5)

The problem is that allowInterop produces "JSFunction" - deprecated class for internal use.

And from point of view of annotations - there should be normal "Function" class.

This is annoying if to pay attention to this. And if I will not pay attention to analyzer errors - I may leave real error in my code.

How can I fix it?

P.S. Using latest dart 1.16

Update: created issue at github https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26371

Comment: I just tested your sample and I don't see any analyzer issue.

Comment: Strong mode  analyzer is necessary